# Merge two arrays into one associative array

Tags: php, arrays

I have two arrays that I want to merge into one associative array. 
My first array looks like this:

```
$names_array = ["John", "Paul", "George"];
```

The second one looks like this:

```
$ages_array = [26, 29, 22];
```

I would like to merge these two arrays and obtain this structure:

```
$members_infos = [{"name": "John", "age": 26}, {"name": "Paul", "age": 
29}, {"name": "George", "age": 22}];
```

Do I have to use a for loop in order to achieve what I want or can use a php function ?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

It's a work for [array_map](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) function

```
$res = array_map(function ($name, $age) { return ['name'=> $name, 'age'=>$age]; },
          $names_array, $ages_array);
```

Answer (score 0):

By using array combine function you can join names, ages

```
$names_array = ["John", "Paul", "George"];
    $ages_array = [26, 29, 22];
    $result = [];
    $members_infos = array_combine($names_array,$ages_array);
    foreach ($members_infos as $key => $value) {
        $result[] = ['name'=>$key, 'age'=>$value];
    }

    $output = json_encode($result);
    echo "<pre>"; 
    print_r($output);
    echo "</pre>";
    exit;
```