# How do i merge these arrays into one

Tags: php, arrays, array-merge

I want to change the following php array

```
  "extra_charge_item" => [
    0 => "Massage",
    1 => "Pool table",
    2 => "Laundry"
  ],
  "extra_charge_description" => [
    0 => "Paid",
    1 => "Paid",
    2 => "We wash everything"
  ],
 "extra_charge_price" => [
    0 => "200",
    1 => "100",
    2 => "1000"
  ],
```

I haven't been able to solve for a whole 2hrs

This is the expected output

```
"new_data" => [
    0 => [
         "Maasage", "Paid", "200"
         ],
    1 => [
         "Pool table", "Paid", "100"
         ],
    2 => [
         "Laundry", "we wash everything", "1000"
         ]
  ]
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: array_merge().. I just cant seem to get exactly what i want

Comment: array_merge makes very little sense for this.

Comment: `array_column` can help you extract the values at a given index position. Combine with implode, and you got the data for one element of your target array already. Now repeat for the other two index positions, and ... done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer. Seems someone else had the same problem

[Merge two arrays into one associative array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47282527/merge-two-arrays-into-one-associative-array)

Here's the solution for my case;

```
//These are arrays passed from front end in the name attribute e.g extra_charge_item[] e.t.c
$extra_charge_item_array = $request->input('extra_charge_item');
$extra_charge_description_array = $request->input('extra_charge_description');
$extra_charge_price_array = $request->input('extra_charge_price');

$new_extra_charges_data = array_map(
       function ($item, $description, $price) {
                 return [
                        'item' => $item,
                        'description' => $description,
                        'price'=> $price
                 ];
       }, $extra_charge_item_array, $extra_charge_description_array, $extra_charge_price_array);

//save the data
foreach ($new_extra_charges_data as $extra_charge) {
         Charge::create([
               'item' => $extra_charge['item'],
               'description' => $extra_charge['description'],
               'price' => $extra_charge['price']
         ]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Rather than doing all the work for you, here's some pointers on one way to approach this:

1. If you are happy to assume that all three sub-arrays have the same number of items, you can use [array_keys](https://php.net/array_keys) to get those keys from whichever you want.
2. Once you have those keys, you can use a [foreach loop](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) to look at each in turn.
3. For each key, use [square bracket syntax](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#language.types.array.syntax.accessing) to pluck the three items you need.
4. Use [`[$foo, $bar, $baz]` or `array($foo, $bar, $baz)`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#language.types.array.syntax.array-func) to create a new array.
5. Assign that array to your final output array, using the key from your `foreach` loop.

Answer (score 0):

Just use [foreach](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) with *key* => *value*

```php
$data = [
    "extra_charge_item" => [
        0 => "Massage",
        1 => "Pool table",
        2 => "Laundry"
    ],
    "extra_charge_description" => [
        0 => "Paid",
        1 => "Paid",
        2 => "We wash everything"
    ],
    "extra_charge_price" => [
        0 => "200",
        1 => "100",
        2 => "1000"
    ],
];
$newData = [];
foreach ($data as $value) {
    foreach ($value as $k => $v) {
        $newData[$k][] = $v;
    }
}

var_dump($newData);
```